# Compressing the core files during core generation

Tags: linux, kernel

Is there way to compress the core files during core dump generation?

If the storage space is limited in the system, is there a way of conserving it in case of need for core dump generation with immediate compression?

Ideally the method would work on older versions of linux such as 2.6.x.

Answer (score 21):

The Linux kernel `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file will do what you want: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#191

Set the filename to something like `|/bin/gzip -1 > /var/crash/core-%t-%p-%u.gz` and your core files should be saved compressed for you.

Comment: Note that this is only supported as of 2.6.19.  If you have an embedded system running something earlier, it might be an inspiration to upgrade ;-)

Comment: Also worthy of note for embedded people, most of the direct flash filesystems (yaffs, jffs2, ubifs) do transparent compression on files, which will achieve a similar net effect.

Comment: The  program must be specified using an absolute pathname. see [CORE(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html).
Also the redirection ">" does not seam to work in here, you can put the gzip command into a separate shell script like "/root/core.sh", then `echo "|/root/core.sh" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` instead.

Comment: @Ted, I'm surprised I overlooked the full path. Thanks!

Comment: Same for me on busybox: one should specify the core patterns as arguments to the shell script, e.g. `echo "|/root/core.sh %t %p %u" >/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` and inside the script you can use $1, $2, $3:
`/bin/gzip -f - >/var/crash/core-$1-$2-$3.gz`

Comment: I had to take this one step further and add the shell environ to core.sh:
`#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/pigz -f - >"/data/cores/core-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5.gz"` and core_pattern: `|/usr/local/sbin/core.sh %e %p %h %s %t`

Answer (score 2):

For an embedded Linux systems, following script change  perfectly works to generate compressed core files in 2 steps

### step 1: create a script

`touch /bin/gen_compress_core.sh`
`chmod +x /bin/gen_compress_core.sh`

`cat  > /bin/gen_compress_core.sh  #!/bin/sh exec /bin/gzip -f - >"/var/core/core-$1.$2.gz"` 
`ctrl +d`

### step 2: update the core pattern file

`cat  > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern |/bin/gen_compress_core.sh %e %p ctrl+d`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other answer, the Linux kernel /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file is good place to start: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt#141

As documentation says you can specify the special character "|" which will tell kernel to output the file to script. As suggested you could use |/bin/gzip -1 > /var/crash/core-%t-%p-%u.gz as name, however it doesn't seem to work for me. I expect that the reason is that on my system kernel doesn't treat the > character as a output, rather it probably passes it as a parameter to gzip.

In order to avoid this problem, like other suggested you can create your file in some location I am using /home//crash/core.sh, create it using the following command, replacing  with your user. Alternatively you can also obviously change the entire path.

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nexec /bin/gzip -f - >"/home/<username>/crashes/core-$1-$2-$3-$4-$5.gz"' > ~/crashes/core.sh
```

Now this script will take 5 input parameters and concatenate them and add to core-path. The full paths must be specified in the ~/crashes/core.sh. Also the location of this script can be specified. Now lets tell kernel to use tour executable with parameters when generating file:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="|/home/<username>/crashes/core.sh %e %p %h %t"
```

Again  should be replaced (or entire path to match location and name of core.sh script).  Next step is to crash some program, lets create example crashing cpp file:

```
int main (){
    int * a = nullptr;
    int b = *a;
}
```

After compiling and running there are 2 options, either we will see:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Or

> Segmentation fault

In case we see the latter, there are few possible reasons.

1. ulimit is not set, ulimit -c should specify what is limit for cores
2. apport or your distro core dump collector is not running, this should be investigated further
3. there is an error in script we wrote, I suggest than checking some basic dump path to check if the other things aren't reason the below should create /tmp/core.dump:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern="/tmp/core.dump"
   ```

I know there is already an answer for this question however it wasn't obvious for me why it isn't working "out of the box" so I wanted to summarize my findings, hope it helps someone.

Comment: what is $5 in your script?

Comment: it's script from 2019 :D I don't remember - you can pass anythiung as parameteres 1,2,3,4 and 5. It will just append them after dashes to filename. If you leave it empty it will be emtpy string.

Comment: ok. it is just that you pass 4 arguments to core.sh "%e %p %h %t", but then use 5 positional arguments in the script itself. there is an inconsistency there.