# Is there any methods to solve segment fault?

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I am working on a IoT linux device. There is segment fault when running my applicantion. I need some methods to solve this problem.

Methods that I have tried:

1.coredump

ulimit -c unlimited; unlimit -f unlimited; 
core will create, but maybe the chip's memory is not enough, so the core is always truncatured. I cannot use gdb to get the backtrace.

2.dmesg | grep segfault

This linux system does not save crash in "demsg"

3./var/log/messages

This linux system does not save crash in "/var/log/messages"

Do you have any suggestion to solve segment fault? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, learn how to debug your program. See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). [Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is an instance of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You could consider [remote debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Debugging.html)

Comment: Also, understand that a SegFault is generally the result of assigning an invalid address to (or failing to initialize) a pointer and then attempting to access the value at that invalid address. When "talking to the Rubber Duck" at the link provided above, double-check any use of pointers, the addresses they are assigned or their uninitialized use. Enable full warnings for your compiler, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic ...` (at minimum) and don't accept code until it compiles without warning..

Comment: [How to use gdb for memory errors](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+gdb+for+memory+errors), [How to use valgrind for memory errors](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+valgrind+for+memory+errors), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Valgrind. It helped us a lot when we were trying to find data that is written out of bounds of an array. It is good for checking memory leaks, out-of-boundary cases and segmentation faults. Actually we just used it to check all of our C/C++ programs later and found a lot of undetected bugs.

Note: Don't forget to compile your program with debug information (e.g. '-g' switch of gcc compiler) to get  more human readable messages in Valgrind. Check [this quick start guide](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html).

Answer (score 0):

Coredumps can be large, but in my experience they contain huge chunks of zeros, so they can be easily compressed. Using the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file, you can get the kernel to pipe the dump through gzip, so that it takes less space ( [compressing the core file during core generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063295/compressing-the-core-file-during-core-generation) ).

Another option would be to try the -fsanitize family of gcc options. More specifically -fsanitize=address and -fsanitize=undefined. If you do that, your application will print a lot of useful information when it crashes (often including the actual file and line number where the crash occured). Oh and don't forget to copy the corresponding shared libraries to your target, otherwise the dynamic linker will throw an error when you try to run the instrumented application.

Comment: I use -fsanitize and found the problem. The first method that to pipe the coredump dosen't work on my device. Thank you very much.