# GDB - Createing a compressed core file on the fly

Tags: c, linux, gdb, compression, gzip

GDB provides a functionality to create coredump of a running-process, and there is a nice script - 'gcore'  to provide simple abstraction. If anybody want a compressed 'core' file it is a two step process:

1. Create coredump of the running process
2. Use gzip or similar utility to compress coredump.

But if one is pressed against available disk-space, It would be good to have compression at step#1, before the file is being written on the disk. I made changes in initial routines of gdb, such that it only creates coredump,by jumping to gcore_command() routine:

```
#0  0x00007f48876bb140 in write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f48876461a3 in _IO_new_file_write () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4887646a40 in __GI__IO_file_xsputn () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007f488763b692 in fwrite () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x000000000072c04d in cache_bwrite (abfd=<optimized out>, from=0x1fe0ba0, nbytes=16384) at cache.c:387
#5  0x000000000072b44a in bfd_bwrite (ptr=ptr@entry=0x1fe0ba0, size=size@entry=16384, abfd=abfd@entry=0x1f13800) at bfdio.c:233
#6  0x0000000000751f6e in _bfd_elf_set_section_contents (abfd=0x1f13800, section=0x1fff950, location=0x1fe0ba0, offset=<optimized out>, count=16384) at elf.c:8878
#7  0x0000000000731264 in bfd_set_section_contents (abfd=0x1f13800, section=0x1fff950, location=0x1fe0ba0, offset=<optimized out>, count=<optimized out>) at section.c:1512
#8  0x00000000005b654c in gcore_copy_callback (obfd=0x1f13800, osec=0x1fff950, ignored=<optimized out>) at gcore.c:576
#9  0x000000000073110c in bfd_map_over_sections (abfd=0x1f13800, operation=0x5b64d0 <gcore_copy_callback(bfd*, asection*, void*)>, user_storage=0x0) at section.c:1374
#10 0x00000000005b6923 in gcore_memory_sections (obfd=0x1f13800) at gcore.c:604
#11 write_gcore_file_1 (obfd=0x1f13800) at gcore.c:102
#12 write_gcore_file (obfd=0x1f13800) at gcore.c:123
#13 0x00000000005b6b2e in gcore_command (args=<optimized out>, from_tty=<optimized out>) at gcore.c:169
#14 0x0000000000459049 in cmd_func (cmd=<optimized out>, args=<optimized out>, from_tty=<optimized out>) at cli/cli-decode.c:1857
#15 0x00000000006bcd9f in execute_command (p=<optimized out>, p@entry=0xcf14e0 <lc_gcore_cmd_str> "gcore /tmp/server.core.15.29219", from_tty=from_tty@entry=0) at top.c:630
#16 0x0000000000604c78 in catch_command_errors (command=0x6bc990 <execute_command(char const*, int)>, arg=0xcf14e0 <lc_gcore_cmd_str> "gcore /tmp/server.core.15.29219", from_tty=0)
    at main.c:381
#17 0x0000000000605a18 in captured_main_1 (context=0x7, this=<optimized out>) at main.c:1129
#18 captured_main (data=0x7) at main.c:1155
#19 gdb_main (args=args@entry=0x7fff20538bc0) at main.c:1184
```

Can I call a compression API in cache_bwrite() before calling fwrite()? or Is there any other better way?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to set `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to pipe the coredump directly into e.g. gzip: `|/bin/gzip > /tmp/dump.gz`  and then killing the process: `kill -SEGV <pid>` (see [Naming of core dump files](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) / [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063295/compressing-the-core-files-during-core-generation) ) (if killing the process is an option) - `gcore` won't work most likely because it uses `fseek` / `ftell`, so no dumping to streams. ([gdb issue](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25510))

Comment: If you want to modify the gcc code to make it work would either need to fix the issue above (remove usages of `fseek`) to be able to use a normal compression algorithm (e.g. gzip, lzma,...) or use a custom compression algorithm that can deal with `fseek` (i.e. compress the files in 4kb chunks, so you only need to recompress 4kb each time you need to do a fseek). imho either options would be quite a lot of work. so i would use the `core_pattern` method, since that works out of the box.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Turtlefighh, letting kernel do  coredump is not an option, because  I want to keep process alive. So I want to pause (not kill) the inferior process to create a snapshot and then let it continue.

As you pointed, gcore is using fseek() and ftell() to add bfd section notes, so  file stream can't be duped to a compression utility. So I guess options are: either  redesign code around fseek() or write in a cached-buffer of 4K and pass it to compression utility.

Thanks once again for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @xchitan in that case it might be an option to e.g. add a SIGUSR1 signal handler to your process that forks the process and calls abort in the child. That way you get a full core dump without interrupting the main process.

Comment: @Turtlefight Yes about that -  application is heavily multi-threaded, and the core file generated with fork() and abort() will have stack of the thread calling fork() - not the other threads.

Comment: Then maybe the Google coredumper library might be an option - it can create multithreaded compressed coredumps (`GetCompressedCoreDump()`) see [google coredumper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/wikis) or the [github mirror](https://github.com/anatol/google-coredumper)

Comment: @Turtlefight Thanks for your response. I had spent time exploring  google coredumper library.  It was abandoned by Google in 2008, and later adopted by [Percona Labs](https://github.com/Percona-Lab/coredumper) - I'm not sure if there are any plans of actively maintaining it for future kernel release, so that's a concern. 
Yet I tried, and could make it work for x86, but ran into problems for MIPS. It was at this point, I considered tapping into GDB  to get live core snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I recently open-sourced [this project corepipe](https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/corepipe), to take a coredump to a pipe, you might give it a try?

Build it, then run `corepipe 1234 | gzip > core.1234.gz` (where 1234 is the pid).